# sed replace base64 encoded images in bulk

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to use sed to recursively find/replace several base64 encoded images from files.

every image embed starts with `src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,` and ends with `+"`

I've tried this, but couldnt get it to work: `find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i 's/.*src=\"data\:image\([^;]*\)+\".*/\/path\/to\/image.png/g' {} +`

I'm pretty new to regex and sed; I'm expecting something wrong with the regex match or escaping.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `s` with `sed` it will replace the entire pattern that it matches, so you probably don't want the `.*` at the start and end of the pattern you actually want to replace.

You can also use different delimiters with sed than `/` which is handy if you have `/` in either of the part of the substitution, as you have in the path.  So we can try a different substitution like:

```
sed 's_"data:image[^"]*"_/path/to/image.png_g' your_file
```

This will find everything that start with `"data:image` and ends with the next `"`, which I'm guessing will work, though you didn't give much sample data to show whether the `+"` was really important, or the `"` itself is sufficient.

We can test this match with

```
$ echo '<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,+">' | sed 's_"data:image[^"]*"_/path/to/image_g'
<img src=/path/to/image>
```

So you can use that `sed` command in your find.  I assume you're using gnu's sed since you're using `-i` like that.  If you have a different sed, you'll probably need to fix that part of your command too.

Comment: Thank you - the '+' was just the end of the encoding for the image and the '"' just the end of the wrapping 'src=" "'

I tested your edit and it works perfectly - I added quotes around the image to replace path 's_"data:image[^"]*"_"/path/to/image.png"_g'

thanks a lot for your answer - I learned something new about 'sed' today!